# Nested Interface & Abstract Implementation Class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, interface, abstract-class, nested-class

I accidentally came across this in C# 4.0 when I was trying to implement a nested interface with an abstract class:

```
public class A
{
    public interface InnerInterface
    {
        void Method();
    }
}

public abstract class B : A.InnerInterface
{
    public abstract void A.InnerInterface.Method();
}

public class C : B
{
    public override void A.InnerInterface.Method()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("C::A.InnerInterface.Method()");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the above code fails to compile, with the following errors:

> error CS0106: The modifier 'abstract' is not valid for this item
>
> error CS0106: The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item
>
> error CS0106: The modifier 'override' is not valid for this item
>
> error CS0106: The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item

However if the interface is instead a non-nested interface, like this:

```
public interface SomeInterface
{
    void Method();
}


public abstract class B : SomeInterface
{
    public abstract void Method();
}

public class C : B
{
    public override void Method()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("C::Method()");
    }
}
```

It compiles OK.

Why the compiler error in the first case? Am I missing something here? Or is it not allowed to implement a nested interface with an abstract class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with the nesting - it's with explicit interface implementation. If you change your "working" example to use:

```
public abstract void SomeInterface.Method()
```

you'll see the same problem. You should be able to use implicit interface implementation with a nested interface easily:

```
public abstract class B : A.InnerInterface
{
    public abstract void Method();
}

public class C : B
{
    public override void Method()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("C::A.InnerInterface.Method()");
    }
}
```

... and if you *want* to use explicit interface implementation, it should work in the same way for a nested interface as a non-nested one. But you don't write `public` on explicit interface implementations, and they can't be abstract either (IIRC).

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know there is implicit/explicit interface implementation in C#